# Reading a csv into a unordered_map in C++

Tags: c++, csv, c++11

I'm trying to read a csv file and store it in a hashmap in C++. Here's my code.

```
 void processList(std::string path, std::unordered_map<std::string, int> rooms){

            std::ifstream openFile(path);
            std::string key;
            int value;
            std::getline(openFile, key, ','); //to overwrite the value of the first line
            while(true)
            {
                if (!std::getline(openFile, key, ',')) break;

                std::getline(openFile, value, '\n');
                rooms[key] = value;
                std::cout << key << ":" << value << std::endl;
            }
    }
```

I keep getting the following error

```
error: no matching function for call to 'getline'
            std::getline(openFile, value, '\n');
```

What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`std::getline` expects an `std::string` as its second parameter. You should pass an `std::string` object to `getline` and then use `std::stoi` to convert that string to `int`.

Like this:

```
std::string valueString;
std::getline(openFile, valueString, '\n');
auto value = std::stoi(valueString);
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::getline`:

```
template< class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator >
std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& getline( std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& input,
                                       std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>& str,
                                       CharT delim );
```

The second arg of `std::getline` must be `std::string`.
As such, read `value` as `std::string` and convert it to `int`.

```
std::string _value;
int value;
std::getline(openFile,_value,'\n');
value = std::stoi(_value);
```